# How to initialize an array inside a map in Go?

Tags: dictionary, go, graph

I want to make an adjacency list from an array of array which represent the edges of a graph, but I am confused how to initialize an empty array if there is a new key to the adjacency list (a map data structure).

This is the type of my adjacency list:

```golang
graph := make(map[int][]int)
```

I don't know how to initialize it.

```golang
func AdjacencyList() {
    edges := [][]int{
        {0, 1},
        {1, 2},
        {0, 3},
        {0, 4},
    }
    graph := make(map[int][]int)
    for _, element := range edges {
        val, ok := graph[element[0]] ;ok {
            graph[element[0]] = append(graph[element[0]], element[1])
        }else {
            graph[element[0]] = make([]int)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When initializing slices `make` requires a length argument. For maps it's optional which is why `make(map[int][]int)`, but for slices it's required, which is why `make([]int)` doesn't work. The compiler error ought to be pretty clear: `invalid operation: make([]int) expects 2 or 3 arguments; found 1`.

Comment: does that mean we can't make a map of arrays?

Comment: No, that's not at all what the previous comment claims. It says, that to initialize a *slice* with `make` you MUST, in addition to the type, provide at least the `length` argument.

Comment: can you give me a code example with `make` function?

Comment: `make([]int, 0)`

Comment: and how can I assign this `make([]int, 0)` to a map?

Comment: With the assignment operator `=` of course, how else?

Comment: You don't really need to use `make` in this context. You could just use `[]int{element[1]}`. Save `make` for when you need to pre-allocate a certain amount of memory in order to avoid having to use several allocations which interrupt execution.
https://go.dev/play/p/xjQ4Kkt-MxS

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, thank but it would be useful to know how to make an initialization  with `make([]int,0)` . thank you for your suggestion.